# Is it possible to decrypt a file in Python using OpenSSL?

Tags: python, encryption, openssl

In windows CMD I'm using the following command line:

```
openssl.exe bf -in inputfile.bin -out outputfile.tar.gz -d -k 123mysecretkeygoeshere456
```

This works perfectly.
The encrypted binary file is decrypted and can be opened in 7zip.

How could I do the same thing in Python?
I am not finding anything online.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```py
import os
os.system("openssl.exe bf -in inputfile.bin -out outputfile.tar.gz -d -k 123mysecretkeygoeshere456
```